# Why getting no such file or directory error?

Tags: tomcat, playframework

I have a we application and i want to move this application from windows to linux.Here for uploading files i haven path as "/var/www/html/pdfs/".But after deploying war file and running under tomcat,When uploading the files we are getting error.In tomcat logs there is error occurred as No such file or directory,Action controller  does not go to inside method also.Please help me why i am getting no such file or no directory error before method calling?For all help thanks in advance.

```
public static Result uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() throws Exception {

    Logger.info("@C HoForms -->> uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice() -->> ");

    //final String basePath = System.getenv("INVOICE_HOME");
    final String basePath = "/var/www/html/pdfs/";
    File ftemp = new File(basePath + "HeadOfficeForms\\" + formType
                + "");// for play & tomcat also
        ftemp.mkdirs();
    File f1 = new File(ftemp.getAbsolutePath() + "//" + fileName);
        File file = upFile.getFile();

        file.setWritable(true);
        file.setReadable(true);
        f1.setWritable(true);
        f1.setReadable(true);
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), f1.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING);
        HoForm.create(fileName, date, formType, filePathString);
        flash("success", fileName + "  Has been Successfully Uploaded");
  }
```

Comment: Check the permissions, make sure that the tomcat user has access to read/write those files..

Comment: i checked for permissions,It shows 777 what it means?

Comment: Is play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData  is worked for https protocol?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace please?